# React - Jest/Enzyme changed trigger function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I've this code:

```
// button.js


const Button = ({ callbackRequestId, message }) => {
  const [isSending, setIsSending] = useState(false);

  const resendCallback = callbackRequestId => {
    setIsSending(true);
    setOpen(false);

    http
      .post(`/callback_request`, {})
      .then(response => {
        if (response) setIsSending(false);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(error);
      })
      .then(() => {
        setIsSending(false);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {isSending ? (
        <CircularProgress size={25} />
      ) : (
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          id="send-callback-button"
          size="small"
          color="primary"
          onClick={resendCallback}
        >
          Resend
        </Button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

// test case

it('should trigger agree confirmation dialog', () => {
    const button = wrapper.find('#send-callback-button');

    button.simulate('click');

    const dialog = wrapper.find(ConfirmationDialog).shallow();

    dialog.find('#ok-button').simulate('click');

    expect(mockCallBack).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The problem is `resendCallback` function has http request that requires Authorization.
My question is:
How to ignore it or change it to `jest.fn()` so its not returning error?

I want to test that `isSending` become `true` and it render `CircularProgress`, but because of the http the test case is failed.

Comment: Of course you should mock the `http` object in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test file, mock the module function with

```
import http from 'http';
jest.mock('http');
```

and in your test let the mock return the value of `post` with `mockResolvedValue` :

```
it('should trigger agree confirmation dialog', () => {
    http.post.mockResolvedValue(<response>); // return whatever value you want
    const button = wrapper.find('#send-callback-button');

    button.simulate('click');

    const dialog = wrapper.find(ConfirmationDialog).shallow();

    dialog.find('#ok-button').simulate('click');

    expect(http.post).toHaveBeenCalled()
});
```